# .jar file will not open on my Mac

Tags: java, macos, oracle, minecraft

I'm using a Macbook Pro running 10.7.5 Lion and I'm trying to open a Java .jar file with Jar Launcher v. 14.8.0. It returns the following error message:

```
The Java Jar file "1.6.2Mod.jar" could not be launched.
Check the Console for possible error messages.
```

On checking the console, I find this error message:

```
7/31/13 2:07:11.415 PM [0x0-0xa89a89].com.apple.JarLauncher: Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.Main
```

Any ideas on why this is not working? I am running Oracle's Java, Version 7 Update 25.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Inside the jar, there should be a file:

```
META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
```

Inside this text file, you should have at least:

```
Main-Class: net.minecraft.client.Main
```

and make sure you have this inside the jar:

```
net-.
    |
    minecraft-.
              |
              client-.
                     |
                     Main.class
```

Any extra jars should be listed with the manifast element `Class-Path`.

---

For more no this:

- [Working with Manifest Files: The Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html)

Comment: To look inside the jar file, unzip it. Any jar file is really just a zip file. To unzip, use either Apple's Archive Utility bundled with your Mac or use the App Store to get the free-of-cost app "The Unarchiver". If you have difficulty getting either app to recognize your jar file, then make a duplicate of the jar file and change the ".jar" to ".zip". Alternatively, you can also use the "jar" command-line tool bundled with Java to explode a jar.